# Publishing a web2py site on a local network

Tags: webserver, local, web2py

I'm ready to allow other users to log into my we2py site, all of whom are on the same network as me. I know that on the web2py app, where you start the server, I can specify a local or public Server IP. I selected this and started the server, then went to another machine on the network and tried:
http://*my IP address*:8000/*my app name*/default/landing_view.html

The site appeared, but without any formatting at all. When I tried to log in the next page attempted to open a local copy of the page (C:\ etc).

Edit: I've just realised that on my home network on the Web2py interface I have an extra Public server IP address entry that is missing when I join the work network. Is anyone aware of a setting anywhere to bring back my locally assigned IP address so I can run this site here? Here's a screenshot from work:

[image]

My question is, how do I successfully serve a web2py site from my computer (and soon the server) over a local network?

Thanks all, hope you can help.

Comment: Can you check if there are any errors in developer console on client computer?

Comment: Hi Gaurav! Thanks for answering. Trying this again at home today I can see on the web2py app I can see 4 options: Local(IPv4), Local (IPv6), Public (*server-assigned IP address*) and Public (0.0.0.0). I can successfully connect to http://*server assigned IP address*:8000/*app name*/default/landing_view.html. I'm sure that at work the *server assigned IP address* was not populated. I'll check again